# Measuring waist of a person using Microsoft Kinect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect

I am trying to create an application which is able to accurately measure the body parameters of a person like height, shoulder width and waist.
Currently I have been able to determine the height and the shoulder width of a person using skeletal tracking. 
Can anybody help me out regarding how to measure the waist of a person using a Kinect!
I am coding in C# in Visual Studio.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Show us the code you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give you the exact code, right now, but the recipe:

First you need to understand what it entails. Every person has different proportions. Someone has a wide waist, but fit (athletic), someone has a wide waist, but has also big belly (fat figure), another has a wasp waist. Such variations are many and many...

So, you have to shoot waist in time during rotation around its axis. Then the measured width values convert to a model. After that you will read circumference of the waist plan (like from a blueprint).

**EDIT:**

Detailed:

If a person turns around (you know it, because the waist witdh values changes...front-left-back-rigth-front and many samples between each part of rotation) gives you the measures in time for the pattern.
Split whole time of rotation to number of samples. Each sample will determine the proportional angle of the turn. (8 samples per rotation means one sample is 45° [360°/8=45°]). Now imagine the circle. Split it into 8 circle chords. Each chord have length of the value measured during the rotation.

If the sample count is good enough, now you can reckon the circumference of the polygon. If the count of samples is too low, you can interpolate (or use another solution) the "missing" samples. The more samples you have, the more accurate result you have.

[image]

Comment: How can I measure the circumference of the waist of the person after creating the 3d model?

Comment: Please, see the EDIT part of the answer. I tried to describe this part of recipe in more details.

Comment: BTW: 3D model not needed, 2D is good enough